# How to get TimeZone in low API levels?

Tags: java, android, timezone

The goal is to get the device `TimeZone` using `TimeZone.getDefault()`; however, this dependency needs an API level of 24 or above, which is higher than the project minimum SDK version.

Are there any other solutions to retrieve the device `TimeZone` in lower API levels?

Comment: [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html) is available since API level 1.

Comment: I’m not an Android developer, but the way I read https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html, `getDefault()` seems to be in API level 1 too.

Comment: If you aren’t afraid of an external library, I’d expect that you can use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) with low API levels too. It’s not something I know. ThreeTenABP will allow `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just a small mistake. I was importing `android.icu.util.TimeZone` instead of `java.util.TimeZone`.

The correct import for `TimeZone` in this case is:

```java
import java.util.TimeZone;
```